How to find occurrence of values in column that contains a single list in Grafana?
I have a Grafana dashboard that has Elasticsearch as its datasource. The JSON logs are parsed using the Extract Fields transformation and have a table that looks something like this



ID
Field1
Field2




A
[ "Value-1", "Value-2" ]
Example 1


B
[ "Value-1" ]
Example 2


C
[ "Value-2", "Value-3" ]
Example 3



I want to count the occurrences of each value inside the list of Field1. For example, this is the desired table that I want to create.



Field1
Count




"Value-1"
2


"Value-2"
2


"Value-3"
1



My initial approach was to figure out a transformation that could convert the list values into separate rows. Then, I could do a Group By transformation and count each value. But I cannot find a transformation that could do what I have described. The table would look like this:



ID
Field1
Field2




A
"Value-1"
Example 1


A
"Value-2"
Example 1


B
"Value-1"
Example 2


C
"Value-2"
Example 3


C
"Value-3"
Example 3



Is there a way to do such transformation? Or is there a better approach I should take?
